# Why CPU Utilization on VM Instance has intervals? (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm new to the google cloud platform and currently trying to understand the CPU utilization chart. (Attaching below).
This is the chart for medium machine type with the 2 reserved vCPUs.

[image]
[image]

What I can't understand is, why CPU utilization has this pattern (line goes up and down, from 5% to 26% again and again), when my machine usage is more or less linear. I know, that small machines are allowing CPU bursting, but it doesn't seem to be an explanation, since my usage never topped the CPU cap.

Details on VM:

- machine type is e2-medium with 2 vCPUs and 4G of memory
- the instance is used as a white label server

Will be grateful for any hint!

Comment: Why do you say that is not CPU burst that cause this graph? It's the most logical explanation, isn't it?

Comment: hm. Probably, I misunderstood how CPU burst works. Please, help me to get this. 
So it goes like that: When usage going up, my server using more power than was allocated for him, it continues going to the top till it can, and after that - it resets to the initial usage of CPU power. That's why I having such a pattern. Is it correct?

Comment: Your graph has no scale. No details on the instance, configuration, applications, etc. There are numerous possibilities. Since your question has no details on what the CPU is doing at each point in time, we can only guess.

Comment: My bad, John. Will update it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Metric you mentioned indicates that some process on your VM uses the CPU in a specific time intervals.

Without more information it's a guessing game to figure out why your chart spikes from 5 to 25% and back.

To nail down the process that's causing it you may try using `ps` or more "human friendly" `htop` commands and see what's going on your system.

for example:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
  397     1 /usr/bin/google_osconfig_ag  0.7  0.0
  437     1 /usr/bin/google_guest_agent  0.5  0.0
  408     1 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share  0.4  0.0
    1     0 /sbin/init                   0.2  0.0
  234     1 /lib/systemd/systemd-journa  0.2  0.0
17419     1 /lib/systemd/systemd --user  0.2  0.0
17416   543 sshd: wb [priv]         0.2  0.0
  575     1 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind  0.1  0.0
  543     1 /usr/sbin/sshd -D            0.1  0.0
```

Here's some tips on [how to use `ps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/show-top-five-cpu-consuming-processes-with-ps) and another usefull [Q & A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324655/finding-the-root-of-high-cpu-load) regarding it.

Have a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28724/404591) - it may give you some insight.

Also - this is what the official [GCP docs say about the CPU usage metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-cpu) collected from the agent running on the VM:

> Percentage of the total CPU capacity spent in different states. This value is reported from inside the VM and can differ from `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization`, which is reported by the hypervisor for the VM. Sampled every 60 seconds.
>
> `cpu_number`: CPU number, for example, "0", "1", or "2". This label is only set with certain Monitoring configurations. Linux only.
>
> `cpu_state`: CPU state, one of [idle, interrupt, nice, softirq, steal, system, user, wait] on Linux or [idle, used] on Windows.